# What is a .lck file and why can't I read it with a buffered reader?

Tags: java, parsing, file-io, web-crawler, crawler4j

I'm trying to use crawler4j to crawl websites. I was able to follow the instructions on the crawler4j website. When it is done it creates a folder with two different .lck files, one .jdb file and one .info.0 file.

I tried to read in the file using the code that I provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15549773/667440) answer to read in the file but it keeps failing. I've used the same function to read text files before, so I know the code works.

I also [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547999/accessing-lck-and-jdb-files-stored-via-web-crawler) someone else that asked the same question a few months ago. They never got an answer.

Why can't I use my code to open and read these .lck files to memory?

Comment: "it keeps failing" is hopelessly vague. What happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crawler4j uses [BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) to store crawl informations. See here in the source.

From the command line you can use DB utils to acces the data. Already covered in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644/examining-berkeley-db-files-from-the-cli).

If you want to access the data in your Java code, you simply import BerkeleyDB library (Maven instruction there) and follow the [tutorial on how to open the DB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/collections/tutorial/opendatabases.html).

Comment: Thanks, I was looking around the crawler4j site looking for what to do with those files but I hadn't found anything.