# What StatisticsDB do in Crawler4j open source code?

Tags: web-crawler, crawler4j

I am trying to understand the **Crawler4j Open source** web crawler. In the mean while I have some doubts, that are as follows,

**Questions:-**

1. What is StatisticsDB do in Counters class., and please explain the following code part,

   ```
    public Counters(Environment env, CrawlConfig config) throws DatabaseException {
       super(config);

       this.env = env;
       this.counterValues = new HashMap<String, Long>();

       /*
        * When crawling is set to be resumable, we have to keep the statistics
        * in a transactional database to make sure they are not lost if crawler
        * is crashed or terminated unexpectedly.
        */
       if (config.isResumableCrawling()) {
           DatabaseConfig dbConfig = new DatabaseConfig();
           dbConfig.setAllowCreate(true);
           dbConfig.setTransactional(true);
           dbConfig.setDeferredWrite(false);
           statisticsDB = env.openDatabase(null, "Statistics", dbConfig);

           OperationStatus result;
           DatabaseEntry key = new DatabaseEntry();
           DatabaseEntry value = new DatabaseEntry();
           Transaction tnx = env.beginTransaction(null, null);
           Cursor cursor = statisticsDB.openCursor(tnx, null);
           result = cursor.getFirst(key, value, null);

           while (result == OperationStatus.SUCCESS) {
               if (value.getData().length > 0) {
                   String name = new String(key.getData());
                   long counterValue = Util.byteArray2Long(value.getData());
                   counterValues.put(name, counterValue);
               }
               result = cursor.getNext(key, value, null);
           }
           cursor.close();
           tnx.commit();
       }
   }
   ```

As far as I understand, it saves the crawled URLS, that helps in the case when crawler crashed, then web crawler does not need to start from the beginning.
**Can you please explain the above code line by line, please.**

2 . I didn't found any good link that explains SleepyCat to me, as Crawlers4j uses SleepyCat to store the intermediate information. So please tell me some good resource, from where I can learn the basics of SleepyCat. (I don't know what is the meaning of Transaction, Cursor used in above code).

Help me please. Looking for your kind reply.

Comment: please upvote / accept if it answered your question

Comment: @JulienS. It aswered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Crawler4j loads the existing statistics from the database, by loading all values from the DB.
In fact the code is pretty much incorrect, since a transaction is opened and no modification to the DB is made. Therefore the lines dealing with tnx could be removed.

Commented line by line :

```
//Create a database configuration object 
DatabaseConfig dbConfig = new DatabaseConfig();
//Set some parameters : allow creation, set to transactional db and don't use deferred    write
dbConfig.setAllowCreate(true);
dbConfig.setTransactional(true);
dbConfig.setDeferredWrite(false);
//Open the database called "Statistics" with the upon created configuration
statisticsDB = env.openDatabase(null, "Statistics", dbConfig);

 OperationStatus result;
//Create new database entries key and values
    DatabaseEntry key = new DatabaseEntry();
    DatabaseEntry value = new DatabaseEntry();
//Start a transaction
    Transaction tnx = env.beginTransaction(null, null);
//Get the cursor on the DB
    Cursor cursor = statisticsDB.openCursor(tnx, null);
//Position the cursor to the first occurrence of key/value
    result = cursor.getFirst(key, value, null);
//While result is success
    while (result == OperationStatus.SUCCESS) {
//If the value at the current cursor position is not null, get the name and the value of     the counter and add it to the Hashmpa countervalues
        if (value.getData().length > 0) {
            String name = new String(key.getData());
            long counterValue = Util.byteArray2Long(value.getData());
            counterValues.put(name, counterValue);
        }
        result = cursor.getNext(key, value, null);
    }
    cursor.close();
//Commit the transaction, changes will be operated on th DB
    tnx.commit();
```

I also answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15660132/what-is-a-lck-file-and-why-cant-i-read-it-with-a-buffered-reader/15706095#15706095).
About SleepyCat, are you speaking about [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleepycat_Software) ?